# There's no dessert like this vs. There's no such dessert as this

Tags: meaning

I was wondering if the following statements mean the same:

There's no dessert like this.

There's no such dessert as this.

It seems pretty obvious that the second one means "There's no such thing as this in the world of desserts or I've never seen it in the world of desserts".

The first one, however, sounds ambiguous  because it could not only mean the same as the other, but also mean "This is the best dessert I've ever enjoyed".

Would my understanding be correct?

Comment: You have pretty much nailed it Choe!

Comment: @Ronald Sole....Thanks. You mean I have their meanings right?

Comment: The first one isn't ambiguous. It *always* means *This is the best...* or *This is so different that there is nothing else like it.*